# get item from object in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, javascript-objects

I have my view as shown below:-

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs"  title="{{tab.name}}" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
        <ion-view style=" ">
            <ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="'true'">
                <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
                               on-refresh="doRefresh(tab.type)">
                </ion-refresher>
                <ion-list style="">
                    <ion-item style="" class="total-center item-divider" ng-repeat="order in orderList['tab.type']">

                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-tab>
```

I have my controller as shown below:-

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { id: "1", type: "PENDING" ,name:"Pending Orders"}
, { id: "2", type: "CONFIRM", name: "Confirmed Orders" }
, { id: "3", type: "CANCEL", name: "Cancelled Orders" }
, { id: "4", type: "REJECTED", name: "Rejected Orders" }
];

$scope.orderList = {
    "PENDING": [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]
    , "CONFIRM": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    , "CANCEL": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    , "REJECTED": [1,2]
}
```

I can loop over tabs and get the tabs. However i cannot loop over the orderlist such that the order type is the same as the current tab type being considered.

Do you guys have an idea about how do i proceed.

Comment: @Chanthu, I have replaced as you suggested, In fact earlier I was doing that, however I was not getting anything populated. However when i go to the next tab I can the orderlist item, now i go to the first one i can get the orderlist item, now i go to the 2nd tab again i get nothing, Can you please suggest how can i correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding quotes around the type.

Try replacing:

```
<ion-item style="" class="total-center item-divider" ng-repeat="order in orderList['tab.type']">
```

with

```
<ion-item style="" class="total-center item-divider" ng-repeat="order in orderList[tab.type]">
```

Note the `'tab.type'` change to `tab.type`

Answer (score 0):

```
order in orderList['tab.type']
```

if you use 'tab.type' angular will take the whole string as property.and it will search for 'tab.type' is available in orderList.thats not you wanted

so If you want to add tab's type in orderList you need to give the value of tabs type by using tab.type instead of 'tab.type'

use the below one

```
order in orderList[tab.type]
```